# Command-line equivalences of some tasks in Synaptic

Tags: command-line, package-management, synaptic

I already use apt-get for most of my package management. Yet, there are times when I occasionally need to use Synaptic to do certain things. I would like to learn the equivalent commands for doing the following things in Synaptic:

- Check a package's dependencies / dependent packages. (This can be done in Synaptic by viewing the properties of a package).
- Browse available packages
- Search (in package names as well as the details/descriptions) for some key. (The search function at the top of synaptic)
- Check if a package is installed or not

Also, is there a way to find packages that are no longer necessary (e.g. a package no longer in use because I removed a dependency). I have a feeling my system is terribly bloated because I removed certain programs and not all the dependencies went with them.

Comment: Visit `man apt` and `man dpkg`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

- Check a package's dependencies / dependent packages. (This can be done in Synaptic by viewing the properties of a package):

  ```
  apt-cache depend 'package-name'
  apt-cache rdepend 'package-name'
  ```
- Browse available packages

  ```
  apt-cache pkgnames
  apt-cache search '.*'
  apt-cache show 'package-name'
  ```
- Search (in package names as well as the details/descriptions) for some key. (The search function at the top of synaptic)

  ```
  apt-cache search pattern
  apt-cache --names-only search pattern
  ```
- Check if a package is installed or not

  ```
  dpkg -l | grep package-name
  ```

The last one could not give the desired result, because when the terminal width is narrow the columns are truncated. Safer alternatives are

```
dpkg-query -Wf '${Package}\n' | grep pkg
dpkg --get-selections | grep pkg
```

Comment: `aptitude` can also help if you need a package manager while not being to access GUI.

Answer (score 8):

To answer your last question about finding packages that are no longer necessary. You can find packages that are no longer necessary by

```
sudo deborphan
```

Also `aptitude` is per default set to automatically remove unused packages, so I'd suggest you use it instead of `apt-get` (it has other nice features too). Note that you may have to install deborphan and aptitude since they're not in the default install (they can be installed via apt-get).

If you wanna stick with apt-get you can removed unused packages with

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

However, I've found that deborphan manages to find more unused packages than both aptitude and apt-get.

Finally, note that both a aptitude and apt-get can remove old packages from the archives on your computer with the `autoclean` option:

```
sudo aptitude autoclean
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Aptitude can also be set so that it does this automatically.

Answer (score 2):

"Also, is there a way to find packages that are no longer necessary (e.g. a package no longer in use because I removed a dependency)."

Install `deborphan`. The default mode gives a list of *library* packages that aren't depended on by anything - you can also use `-a` to get a list of *all* packages [which will obviously include quite a few you want to keep, but you can get an idea of what you have that you may not want that removing won't affect anything else]